# How do I idiomatically turn a text component into an input component on click?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a todo app in React that is basically just a list of items, grouped by category. I want to add functionality such that when I click a single to do(which is a paragraph), it brings up an input with the current text that I can edit and save. How can I do that without manually editing the DOM?

Code:
A single todo item:

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = props => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`item${props.item.purchased ? ' purchased' : ''}`}
      onClick={() => props.toggleItem(props.item.id)}
    >
      <p>{props.item.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

I want to change the toggle to be a radio button and onClick to edit the todo.
[sample image of todos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOslf.png)

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Comment: See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have added a todo item component. Since my question is conceptual, I doubt I need anything more than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will need a prop that updates `item.name` (this will be needed when you will edit the input)

You didn't explained well how you want it to work, so I made an example where you click on the text to edit it to a text input and also have a button to `save` the edit.

```
const Item = props => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  return isEditing ? (
    <div>
      <input
        value={props.item.name}
        onChange={e => props.setItemName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}>Stop Editing</button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div
      className={`item${props.item.purchased ? " purchased" : ""}`}
      onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}
    >
      <p>{props.item.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also created a working [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-text-8htcv) with the behavior you want.

Comment: this is exactly what I was going for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to maintain a state to change between the `TODO Item` & `TODO Input`. Since you are using functional component, you can use `useState` hook from react to maintain the state as shown below

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Item = props => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  if (isEditing) {
    return (
      <div className={`item${props.item.purchased ? ' purchased' : ''}`}>
        <input type="text/radio" value={props.item.name}>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div
        className={`item${props.item.purchased ? ' purchased' : ''}`}
        onClick={() => props.toggleItem(props.item.id)}
      >
        <p>{props.item.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Item;
```

You might need to change the above a bit based on your application structure but this is what you need to follow.